# Pigeonhole Principle encode

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If we want to encode all 26 letters (of the English alphabet) and all ten decimal digits ($0, 1, \ldots, 9$), in strings of length $n$ of bits $0$ and $1$, then what is the smallest number $n$ that works?

Comment: You want to encode 36 things. Since 32 < 36 < 64, you'd need at least 6 bits

Answer (score 1):

You will need the smallest integer number of bits greater than $\log_2(36)$